# Why did github stop hosting gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, github

Why did github stop hosting gems?  And what is currently the most popular host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that GitHub [stopped hosting gems](https://github.com/blog/515-gem-building-is-defunct) because of their move to Rackspace in October 2009:

> Gem building has been disabled since the move to Rackspace. This was because the system had to be rewritten to work with the new architecture and we had to provision an entirely new VM for the sandboxed gem building – things we didn’t want holding up the move.
>
> We will continue to serve old gems at http://gems.github.com/ for at least one year.

The [GitHub RubyGems page](http://gems.github.com/) refers users to http://rubygems.org/.